# I need to count how many cells in a column have data in them

Tags: microsoft-excel

This spreadsheet is a list of names not numbers.  I am drawing a blank on how to count them when its not numbers.  I just need to know the total number of names in each column.  I am sure it is simple but my brain will not do it today.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNTA()`?

Comment: OMG I am an idiot!! Sorry!  That works.

Comment: Actually, COUNTA counts everything; text and true numbers.. If there is a possibility that there may be true numbers lurking in that *list of names not numbers* then you should use `COUNTA(...)-COUNT(...)`. It won't impact calculation lag noticeably if there are no numbers.

Comment: @Bradyt,, better use `COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*")` , counts only Text (Alphabets & Alphanumeric).